# Django app - importing module issues

Tags: python, django, module

I am on Django 1.6 with Python 2.7, getting an issue with importing some custom modules.
On my views.py file, I have `import Mod.mod.module.file`, where the `Mod` folder is stored in the project directory, outside the folders with settings.py and views.py.

The traceback gives me `ImportError: No module named Mod.mod.module.file`

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: directory structure--

- projectFolder

  - project (includes settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py)
  - Mod

    - mod

      - module

        - file
  - appFolder

    - views.py

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing everything... But it looks like you've got a folder at the top that isn't a module. "Mod", does it have a __init__.py file in it? You could also solve this by appending the "module" folder to the Python path. If you want more help paste your full folder structure of your app.

Comment: Apologies for the minimal description, but thanks for responding. The `Mod` does not have init.py, but the inner `mod` does. Do I need an init.py for every folder?

Comment: Well you need a __init__.py in folders you want Python to consider packages. If you don't want to have to do Mod.mod.module you can add "mod" to the python path and thus "module.file" would work. Either way it is more common to write "from app.models import ModelName" than what you have, importing a whole file like that can cause import errors later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With guidance from stormlifter, I fixed the issue by making a init.py file in `Mod` and installing the module with `python setup.py install`. Here is a blog post that was useful as well:
http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2008/09/note-on-python-paths.html

Answer (score 1):

Your "Mod" folder appears to be missing a "**init**.py" which it will need if you want to import from it.

I also don't recommend a capitalized folder in Python, kind of confusing. 
I'd also recommend you add "mod" to your python path so you're not having to do Mod.mod.module you can just do mod.module. I assume you have "mod" (lowercase) as an "INSTALLED_APP" in settings.py? Or is "module" the app? Either way you may want to check out Django's documentation on how to organize a project, especially if this is your first time.